# crm 2013 user import template imports users as disabled

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am using a template that I have downloaded from crm 2013 to import users. I find that the users are imported as disabled and not enabled.

I can't find where I can change that option. Can someone help?

Also - is there anyway I can add the roles in the template as well so that I can create a user and assign the role at the same time?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

J

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant that is one of the restrictions of importing users via the import tool.

However, what you can do is after the import you can select all the users you wish to enable from a view and bulk enable them  by clicking the enable button from the ribbon.

See below post for limitations of import tool.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmcustomereffective/archive/2015/02/03/importing-users-into-dynamics-crm-2013-dynamics-crm-2015.aspx

Thanks

Antony